# Yii DocumentRoot on shared hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii, document-root

I have a big problem with my shared hosting. I have developed my app with this folder structure:

```
/DocumentRoot
  /backend
    /www
  /common
  /frontend
    /www
```

I have asked to change domain's document root to /frontend/www but they didn't support this change. Is there any way to configure .htaccess and the App to work with this folder structure without changing DocumentRoot?

Thanks you

Comment: Does your web host let you put any files above the DocumentRoot?

Comment: Hi Rowan! I have talked with my provider and they allow me one level above DocumentRoot. Any idea? Thank you so much

Comment: It's not that big of a deal to move your frontend/www to DocumentRoot, backend/www to admin and everything else to protected folder. Then you need to configure paths in index.php, admin/index.php and add proper .htaccess to protected folder.

Comment: Thank you Martin! It could be a good solution.